# WAN port 1 is for internet but it's IPv6. Will a device that is not IPv6 compatible be affected if I connect to this port?

Tags: ipv6

Encapsulation mode: PPPoE,
Protocol type: IPv6,
WAN mode: Route WAN,
Service type: Internet.

WAN port 1 is for internet but it's IPv6. I have a device that is not compatible with IPv6. Will it be affected?

Should I call my ISP to change the protocol to IPv4 or just ignore it?

Comment: What are you even talking about. Provide more context.

Comment: So you're saying you have PPPoE-based service from an ISP, but it's IPv6-only? How is the rest of your router set up? I could imagine a scenario where an ISP issues routers that tunnel v4 inside v6 over a v6-only PPPoE link.

Comment: https://ibb.co/jj1nuv this is my router WAN page.

Comment: As indicated by the second to last option, DS-Lite is enabled. You should not change any settings. Do you have IPv4 Internet access according to [this page](http://test-ipv6.com/)?

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use IPv4 and IPv6 simultaneously. Nothing about IPv6 prevents IPv4 from working and, in fact, IPv6 specifically makes allowances for converting IPv4 addresses to IPv6 address syntax.

That said, newer OSes default to trying to communicate via IPv6 anytime it *appears* to be available and if your isp does not fully and properly have IPv6 implemented this can cause your computer to assume the sites you are looking for don't exist... rather than they simply aren't reachable via IPv6. You OS likely provides a means of forcing the use of IPv4 regardless of detected IPv6 support.

In windows, you would simply disable the TCP/IPv6 module for the network adapter in question. For Ubuntu (and likely other Debian-based Linux distros) there is a setting you can change in a file in `/etc` to tell the OS to prefer IPv4 over IPv6.

Comment: https://ibb.co/jj1nuv So everything is fine here?

Comment: If it's working, sure. What's supposed to happen (greatly simplified) is you type in a web address... say `www.google.com`... and your computer contacts the IPv6 DNS servers it's configured to use (likely automatically via DHCP/AutoConfig). If the IPv6 DNS server returns an `AAAA` record it will use that to resolve the IPv6 address of `www.google.com`. If it Returns an `A` record it will use it to resolve an IPv4 address instead. If it returns neither is _should_ query the configured IPv4 DNS servers as a fallback. Whether it gets an `AAAA` or an `A` record from decides the protocol used.

Comment: So if it's working, you likely are using IPv6 when it's available and IPv4 when it's not. If it's not working then your computer may be getting confused when trying to resolve the IPv6 address and insists on trying to talk to the server via IPv6... when it can't.